Tomcat 9.0 and jdk 17 "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start"
I got the error "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start." when using Eclipse. I have found so many solutions when I search, but nothing really solve my problem.
Debug console:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

I've tried:

Changing Tomcat ports
Changing JAVA_HOME link
Tons of recreate, restart, reinstall Tomcat 9.0 and jdk 17, but still doesn't work
I notice that my debug console said something different from the others

Specs:

Eclipse version 2024-06 (Download on original page)
Tomcat v9.0 (Download on Tomcat page, Zip file x64)
jdk 17.0.11 (Download on Oracle, Installer file)




Which release of Eclipse is it, and is this an installed copy of Tomcat or one unpacked from the zip file?

Please add the details as text to your question as follows: go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

It's 2024-6 Eclipse version, the jdk 17 I dowloaded on Oracle (Installer file), the Tomcat I download on their site (Zip file x64)

Oracle 17 is not the Java Runtime that you are using to launch Tomcat. What did your debug console cay different? Why is so much information hidden or filtered out in the image?

org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap is pretty much the first class you load in Tomcat. Please add the screen you reach with Eclipse >> Window >> Preferences >> Tomcat. In a command prompt go to the Tomcat home from that page in subfolder bin and run catalina start. Does Tomcat start?

John Williams, I've try open that catalina file, it pop up and close instantly

I just try start it manually by: set JAVA_HOME and run the startup file of tomcat with cmd. but it only open and close instantly

Try adding a runtime letting Eclipse "download and install" it to a less complicated path (without spaces and characters that might run afoul of character encoding limitations).

it's fixed, thanks everyone

PROBLEM SOLVED
I put it in a unusual named folder, it's fixed by put in another folder with normal English name
Folder name
